# Detect index of multiple maximum in a 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, 2d

Let's say I have a 2D array with a size of m x n elements.
Now, I want to get the indices of all maximums. So the result should be something like:
`[(m1, n1), (m2, n2)]` where `m` and `n` indicate the x and y coordinates of my maximums.

With only one maximum its quite easy, but with more, I'm getting stuck.

```
import numpy as np

pixel = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 189, 12, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 203, 9, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 5, 245, 0, 0, 0, 7, 4, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 250, 8, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
result = np.where(pixel == pixel.max())

print("cross detection at y:", result[0][0], "x:", result[1][0])

print(pixel)
```

Does somebody have an idea? It would be great, thanks!

Comment: can you please define what are those maximums ?.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make numpy.argmax return all occurrences of the maximum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17568612/how-to-make-numpy-argmax-return-all-occurrences-of-the-maximum)

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: 2nd try: basically I have an image which contains some blurred spots and I want to detect the pixel, where these spots are. For example, I have 4 spots, than I expect a list with 4 x,y coordinates. Because of the imaging structure, I know that two points cannot be closer than 20 pixels. Maybe now it gets clearer..

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
x,y = np.where(pixel == np.max(pixel))
```

this will return x axis and y axis of all the elements with maximum values
Now,for your question you can do

```
np.array((x,y)).T
```

[for this last code I look up to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35091879/merge-2-arrays-vertical-to-tuple-numpy)

Comment: Can you add an explanation to explain what this does?

Comment: @squareskittles this will return an array of the all the x-axis and an array of all the y-axis of the element having maximum values.

Comment: Please edit your answer to include this explanation.

Answer (score -1):

Try [numpy.argmax](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html), it returns the indices of the maximum values along an axis.

Comment: ...and as written in the link you provide _"In case of multiple occurrences of the maximum values, the indices corresponding to the **first occurrence** are returned."_. So, a unique maximum per axis