# how merge array in numpy in the specific way?

Tags: numpy

hi I have 3 array and I wanna merge them element by element.for example

```
a=array([3.1, 3.3])
b=array([4.1, 4.3])
c=array([6.1, 1.3])
```

how I merge add them to get this

```
array([3.1, 4.1,6.1],[3.3,4.3,1.3])
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge two arrays vertically to array of tuples using numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35091879/merge-two-arrays-vertically-to-array-of-tuples-using-numpy)

Comment: What have you tried?  `np.array((a,b,c))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first stack the arrays on top of each other

```
a=np.array([3.1, 3.3])
b=np.array([4.1, 4.3])
c=np.array([6.1, 1.3])

stacked = np.vstack([a, b, c])
```

and then transpose the result

```
result = stacked.T
```

which gives

```
>>> result
array([[3.1, 4.1, 6.1],
       [3.3, 4.3, 1.3]])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [374]: a=np.array([3.1, 3.3])
     ...: b=np.array([4.1, 4.3])
     ...: c=np.array([6.1, 1.3])
```

A common way to make a new array from others is with `np.array`:

```
In [375]: np.array((a,b,c))
Out[375]: 
array([[3.1, 3.3],
       [4.1, 4.3],
       [6.1, 1.3]])
```

Those are the numbers; just the layout is different, (3,2) as opposed to its `transpose`.

Or use variations on `concatenate/stack`.  For example:

```
In [380]: np.column_stack((a,b,c))
Out[380]: 
array([[3.1, 4.1, 6.1],
       [3.3, 4.3, 1.3]])

In [381]: np.stack((a,b,c),axis=1)
Out[381]: 
array([[3.1, 4.1, 6.1],
       [3.3, 4.3, 1.3]])
```

Or even one call to `transpose` (though under the cover this first does the [375] step):

```
In [382]: np.transpose((a,b,c))
Out[382]: 
array([[3.1, 4.1, 6.1],
       [3.3, 4.3, 1.3]])
```

These functions are all documented.